503 / 502 Error occured when making axios request to https://www.google.com through squid proxy
I have configured squid proxy in my system as below
export HTTPS_PROXY="<username>:<password>@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>"

Then I am trying to make get request to google.com as below
const instance = axios.create({
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    })
});

instance.get('https://www.google.com')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.status);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error.response.status);
    });

This should result in 200 but it gives 503 or 502 error ramdomly. Why?

Not quite sure how to solve it using env variable, but I had the same problem (using Squid and receiving 502 or 503 statuses) and solved it by this config approach:
const { HttpsProxyAgent } = require('https-proxy-agent');
const { HttpProxyAgent } = require('http-proxy-agent');
const axios = require('axios');


const proxyString = 'http://username:password@proxy:port';

// when proxy is forwarding via https
const httpsAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyString);
// when proxy is forwarding via http
const httpAgent = new HttpProxyAgent(proxyString);

const instance = axios.create({
    httpAgent: httpAgent,
    httpsAgent: httpsAgent
});

instance.get('http://example.com')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error.response ? error.response.status : error.message);
    });

instance.get('https://example.com')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error.response ? error.response.status : error.message);
    });

